# Centrar contenido de columnas dinámicamente con DataTables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

Intento centrar ***n cantidad*** de columnas en una tabla que tiene ***DataTables*** recibiendo el parámetro dinámicamente pero no funciona.

He probado con el siguiente código, pero necesito que el valor sea dinámico, y que las columnas se centren desde la última hasta la primera según el número que mande:

```
function makerDatatable(number){
   $('#myTable').dataTable({
      "columnDefs": [
        {"className": "text-center", "targets": number}
      ]
   }
}
```

Solo se centra la columna con el número específico que recibe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La documentación de DataTables no es tan clara y por lo general se encuentra desactualizada, hace poco tuve el mismo requerimiento y el proceso fue el siguiente:

```
function doDataTable(tableId, rows, colsToCenter=2) {
    colsToBeCentered = [];
    for(i=1; i <= colsToCenter; i++){ //Hacemos un contador sobre el número recibido
        colsToBeCentered.push($(tableId + " th").length - i); //Por cada número tomamos la columna correspondiente, contando desde el final
    }
    $(tableId).DataTable({
        data: rows,
        lengthMenu: [[10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, "All"]],
        pageLength: 25,
        columnDefs: [{ //Centro el contenido de las n últimas columnas
            className: "text-center", "targets": colsToBeCentered
        }],
        hideEmptyCols: true,
        destroy: true
    });
}
```

Por defecto la función va a centrar las últimas dos columnas si no se recibe ingún parámetro, en caso contrario centra la cantidad indicada.

Ojalá sea lo que buscas.

Answer (score 0):

No te compliques. Los puedes resolver [solo con css.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/tbody)

```
#myTable tbody td:eq(0) {
    text-align: left;
}
#myTable tbody td {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Una regla de css bien planteada no rompera tu tabla.

Comment: El problema es centrar solo algunas columnas específicas y más cuando quizá hay tablas que tienen más columnas que otras.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#table').DataTable( {
            "ajax": "archivo.php",
            "order": [],
            "language": {
                "lengthMenu": "Mostrar _MENU_ registros",
                "zeroRecords": "No hay datos - lo siento",
                "info": "Mostrando _PAGE_ de _PAGES_",
                "infoEmpty": "Sin datos",
                "infoFiltered": "(Filtrando de un total de _MAX_ registros)",
                "search": "Buscar",
                "paginate": {
                    "previous": "Anterior",
                    "next": "Siguiente"
                }
            },
            "columns": [
                {data: 'fecha', name: 'fecha', width: '15%'},
                {data: 'rut', name: 'rut', width: '10%'},
                {data: 'nombreafiliado', name: 'nombreafiliado', width: '25%'},
                {data: 'causabloqueo', name: 'causabloqueo', width: '7%'},
                {data: 'desbloqueable', name: 'desbloqueable', width: '3%', className: "text-center"},
                {data: 'observacion', name: 'observacion', width: '30%'}
            ]
        } );
```

esto hace la magia (className: "text-center")

Comment: ¿Qué aprendí aquí? Nada. No dices cual es el problema ni porque está es la solución. Corregir sin educar es repetir el mismo error una y otra vez.

Comment: explicate un poco

Comment: Añade enunciados para que otros usuarios con el mismo problema puedan guiarse y poder comprender mejor tu respuesta, de lo contrario, esta puede dejar de ser válida